# How to display price including tax with formatting?

Tags: plugins

The code below will show the price including TAX and it works for single page, but on category pages it's missing the Thousand Separator and Currency Symbol.

It is showing as `21000.23` and not `21,000.23`.

Here's the code used in the category page.

```
<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_including_tax() ): ?>
<span class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running any number through the function `woocommerce_price()` will format that number with the number of decimals, thousands separator, currency symbol and currency location chosen in the admin.

Add the function to your code snippet should format the price correctly:

```
<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_including_tax() ): ?>
<span class="price"><?php echo woocommerce_price($price_html); ?></span>
```